# R - How to Count Rows in A Data Set by Category

Tags: r

I am working on simple question but cannot find out how to achieve a simple aggregation in R.
I want to **count** rows per category (ID) in a data set with an example below:

```
Date    Col1    Col2    ID
21/01/2003  1   2   1
27/01/2003  3   6   2
28/01/2003  4   5   2
29/01/2003  5   6   3
30/01/2003  1   0   2
```

I have tried *apply functions without luck. The closest answer I could get to my question is using aggregate function:

```
aggregate(fact, by=list(fact$ID), FUN=length)
```

The problem is that it displays all columns in a data set rather than just ID & count. How can i make it better.

```
    Group.1 Date    Col1    Col2  ID
1         1  117     117     117  117
2         2 1041    1041    1041 1041
3         3  243     243     243  243
4         4  474     474     474  474
```

Ideally: I want to rename ID to Category and Count into Volume so it looks like this:

```
    Category Volume 
         1  117 
         2 1041 
         3  243 
         4  474
```

**Update:**

1. I have installed "plyr" & "data.table" packages. And both solutions work perfectly fine.
2. How to achieve the same solution using **out of the box R**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when I want to count the frequency of different values for one variable I use the `table` function instead of `aggregate`. You can pass the output of `table` to the `data.frame` function to get the data structure you want (I used `setNames` to set the variable names):

```
(counts <- setNames(data.frame(table(dat$ID)), c("Category", "Volume")))
#   Category Volume
# 1        1      1
# 2        2      3
# 3        3      1
```

Comment: Thanks josilber for the prompt answer. I get an error: could not find function "setnames".

Comment: @BIDude sorry that's the function from the `data.table` package... the one from base R is `setNames`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count` from `plyr`

```
> library(plyr)
> setNames(count(df, "ID"), c("Category", "Volume"))
#   Category Volume
# 1        1      1
# 2        2      3
# 3        3      1
```